# jquery defered returning data on when

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Hi i'm trying to understand $.deffered. How do i return data once say a computation has been completed?

```
function cube(n)
{
//console.log(n);
return n = Math.pow(n, 3);
}

function compute(n){
    var d = $.Deferred();

    n = cube(n);
    //how do i return n upon completed computation?
    return d.promise(n);
}



$.when(compute(5))
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ysfk00bc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`js` at Question not appear to return value to `jQuery.Deferred()` callback handler `.done()` . See [deferred.resolve()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) .

`jQuery.Deferred()` methods `resolve` , `reject` return value resolved or reason rejected to jQuery deferred methods `.done` , `.fail` , `.then` , `always` .

Try passing `n` as argument to `.resolve()` method of `jQuery.Deferred()` within `compute` , e.g., `d.resolve(n)`.

Would not need to wrap `compute(5)` within `$.when()` - which returns a jQuery promise - as `compute` would return a jQuery promise object to `.done()` at `return d.promise()` .

```js
function cube(n) {
  return Math.pow(n, 3);
}

function compute(n) {
  var d = new $.Deferred();
  n = cube(n);
  // return jQuery promise `n`: `cube(n)`
  d.resolve(n);
  return d.promise();
}

compute(5)
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

compute(2)
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

---

Alternatively utilizing `$.when()` within `compute` , return jQuery promise `n`: `cube(n)`

```js
function cube(n) {
  return Math.pow(n, 3);
}

function compute(n) {
  n = cube(n);
  // return jQuery promise `n`: `cube(n)`
  return $.when(n);
}

compute(5)
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

compute(2)
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```